# MySQL insert into apparently not executing using an HTML form, PHP, and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I am a beginner "programmer" so please excuse my ignorance.  I am using a prepared statement in the interest of security.  The else clause is echoed instead of the INSERT INTO statement executing.  I am passing a hidden value from the HTML form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="EVS1" name="CustomerCode" />
<?php   

include ('../etc/mysql_connect.php');


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$FirstName= trim( $_POST['FirstName'] );
$LastName= trim( $_POST['LastName'] );
$Address1= trim( $_POST['Address1'] );
$Address2= trim( $_POST['Address2'] );
$City= trim( $_POST['City'] );
$State= trim( $_POST['State'] );
$Zip= trim( $_POST['Zip'] );
$Email= trim( $_POST['Email'] );



$calculated_date = date('m-d-Y', time() + 86400 * 42);



$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO xxx SET FirstName = ?,LastName = ?,Address1 = ?,Address2         = ?,City = ?,State = ?,Zip = ?,Email = ?,CustomerCode = CustomerCode,DrawingEntryDate = NOW() ");

$stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $_POST['FirstName'] , $_POST['LastName'], $_POST['Address1'],           $_POST['Address2'], $_POST['City'], $_POST['State'], $_POST['Zip'], $_POST['Email'], $_POST['CustomerCode']);

$stmt->execute();

$affected_rows= mysqli_stmt_affected_rows ($stmt);

  if ($affected_rows ==1){
    echo '<body bgcolor="#F9F9F9"><h2>Thank You!</h2><font type="Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif"              size="3">We have successfully received your entry.  Good luck!<br><br>Names are drawn randomly each month, and notified via email.  If your name is chosen, please expect delivery within 4-6 weeks.  Your order is scheduled to be delivered by '.$calculated_date.'.</font></body>';

      mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
      mysqli_close($dbconnect);

   }  else {
      echo '<body bgcolor="#F9F9F9"><h2>Oops!</h2><font type="Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif" size="3">There is a limit of 1 entry per day.  <b>'.$FirstName.'</b> has already entered on '.$DrawingEntryDate.' .</font></body>';
      echo mysqli_error();

      mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
      mysqli_close($dbconnect);
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have eight parameter place-holders in the query, and attempt to bind nine parameters to it.

Here:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO xxx SET FirstName = ?,LastName = ?,Address1 = ?,Address2 = ?,City = ?,State = ?,Zip = ?,Email = ?,CustomerCode = CustomerCode,DrawingEntryDate = NOW() ");

$stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $_POST['FirstName'] , $_POST['LastName'], $_POST['Address1'], $_POST['Address2'], $_POST['City'], $_POST['State'], $_POST['Zip'], $_POST['Email'], $_POST['CustomerCode']);
```

you have forgotten to put a parameter placeholder for `CustomerCode`.

If you're always going to set `DrawingEntryDate` to NOW(), you can just leave that out of the query and set that column to have a default value.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to make it more clear where the error is and how to amend it? This way it seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, this SQL statement still will not execute and echoes otherwise.  I've made the suggested changes seen below, verified the PHP file is updating on my FTP server, and verified user insert permissions (insert, update and select permissions).             

The Customer Code is a hidden, hard coded value.  I’m not sure if that may make a difference:          

<input type="hidden" value="EVS1" name="CustomerCode" />      

...  ,CustomerCode = ?");       

 sssssssss     …    , $_POST[' CustomerCode ']);

Comment: You'd need to post the latest version. The problem is (or was) that you don't have a ? placeholder in the query you posted for the customer code, you just put "CustomerCode = CustomerCode" instead of "CustomerCode = ?". Then you try to send nine parameters to it, with only eight placeholders. If you checked the return each step of the way I'm sure you'd find that `bind_param` is failing.